# x11 directory specified in makefile doesn't exist, but project compiles and runs perfectly

Tags: x11, makefile, compiler

So the x11 directory defined in the makefile is: usr/X11R6/lib64, which does not exist.
however, the project compiles perfectly in Kdevelop and runs with no problems.

If I take out all inclusions of x11 in the makefile, it doesn't compile.

(1) Does the compiler search for x11 libs somehow if the dir specified does not exist?

(2) How can I find where exactly x11 libs are in my computer?

For (2), I've found /usr/lib/X11, but I can't find any library files in there...

(I am attempting to rewrite the makefile in CMake format in Kubuntu, if that matters at all.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, gcc checks `/usr/include` to satisfy `#include` directives by default.
2. Try `locate -b '\X.h'`. My system finds it in `/usr/include/X11`.